# Anime where character finds buried mech suit

Tags: story-identification, anime, robots, mobile-suit-gundam

I’m looking for an anime I remember from many years ago, I want to say it is a Gundam series but I can’t recall.

I remember the character finding a mecha suit buried for some reason and when he got close to it activated and he became its pilot. Does anyone remember this?

Comment: Hi there! This is a bit vague at the moment, could you take a look at [this guide on how to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) and [this one which deals with anime-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in your question? For instance when did you watch this? 10 years ago, 20? Was it dubbed or just subbed? Things like that, to increase the chances of a successful ID. Cheers!

Comment: This seems really quite broad and fits multiple properties. Finding a mecha suit in anime is a bit like chancing on a Starbucks in real life.

Comment: Sounds like [Tengen Toppa] Gurren Lagann to me - kid finds a mecha head while drilling a tunnel, and uses it to free humanity from mecha-piloting oppressors - but my anime knowledge is limited.

Comment: There are only two Gundam series which involve digging up ancient robots - Turn A Gundam, from 1999, and Iron-Blooded Orphans, from 2015. Neither quite fits, though - the Turn A Gundam was concealed inside a statue, and the first Gundam appearing in Orphans was already restored to functionality and stored for use as a power generator. In both cases, other robots are unearthed later in the series, and are not how the protagonist gets to pilot the main hero robot.

Comment: @Vanguard3000 That was my first thought as well, you should add it as an answer.

Comment: It could also be Mars Daybreak (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Daybreak).

Answer (score 5):

It could be Tengen Toppa Gurren Lagann.

[image: Simon, Kamina, and Yoko look at the Lagann]

> A young boy, Simon, who lives in a subterranean city, discovers a
>   giant robot head while excavating a tunnel. He climbs into it, and a
>   small drill-shaped pendant he's wearing acts as a key, awakening it.
>   With his "brother" Kamina, and a mysterious woman with a giant rifle,
>   Simon uses the head to battle the giant mechas that roam the earth's
>   surface and terrorize the last humans on earth.

While the mecha Simon finds (the *Lagann*) is just basically a head with small arms and legs, he and Kamina are eventually able to capture more mechas, and combine the *Lagann* with a larger body, piloted by Kamina - the *Gurren*.

[image: The Gurren Lagann]

Answer (score 4):

**Break Blade 1: Kakusei no Toki** aired in 2010. The setting is actually more fantasy than sci-fi, but the mechs and general flow of the series are very gundam-esque. The main character is the only one that can pilot an ancient mech that was found buried.
[image]